# Apollo query not triggering useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo

I need a refetch on an Apollo query to trigger useEffect. I'm implementing a filter bar that filters by a date period and a text search. My search submit button triggers the refetch on the query, and the data returned is a dependency of my useEffect. When the data is returned, if the search fields are populated, the filter should run. This works the first time I run a search, but when I reset with my reset function, the reset is triggered and the query gets 200 in Chrome and shows the data in Chrome dev tools, but useEffect is not triggered. Why is this?

```
//React
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react'

//extra React libraries

//external libraries
import { useQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks'

//components
import AccountsGrid from '../../containers/AccountsGrid/AccountsGrid'
import SpinnerLoader from '../../components/SpinnerLoader/SpinnerLoader'

//styles
import styles from "./accounts.module.scss";

//contexts
import UserContext from '../../containers/contexts/UserContext/UserContext'
import AccountContext from '../../containers/contexts/AccountContext/AccountContext'

//constants
import { 
  GET_PARENT_ACCOUNT, 
  SET_ACCOUNTS,
  SET_IS_ACTIVE,
  SET_ACCOUNTS_LIMIT,
  SET_ACCOUNTS_OFFSET,
  SET_ACCOUNTS_TOTAL,
  SET_ACCOUNTS_START_DATE,
  SET_ACCOUNTS_END_DATE,
} from '../../containers/contexts/AccountContext/accountActionTypes'

import { 
  GET_ACCOUNT_USERS,
  GET_ACCOUNTS,
  TOTAL_ACCOUNTS,
  } from '../../utils/constants/queries/accountQueries'

import {
  UPDATE_ACCOUNT
} from '../../utils/constants/mutations/accountMutations'
import moment from 'moment';


function Accounts(props) {
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext)
  const accountContext = useContext(AccountContext)
  const parentAccountID = userContext.userState.accountId
  const [parentAccountIDs, setParentAccountIDs] = useState(null)
  const [sortByField, setSortByField] = React.useState(null);
  const [sortByType, setSortByType] = React.useState(null);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(null);
  const [datesValid, setDatesValid] = React.useState(true);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState("");

  const { 
    loading: loadingAccountUsers, 
    error: errorAccountUsers, 
    data: dataAccountUsers,
    refetch: refetchAccountUsers,
  } = useQuery(GET_ACCOUNT_USERS, {
      variables: {
        accountId: parentAccountID
      }
  })

  const { 
    loading: loadingAccounts, 
    error: errorAccounts, 
    data: dataAccounts,
    refetch: refetchAccounts
  } = useQuery(GET_ACCOUNTS, {
      variables: {
        parentIds: parentAccountIDs,
        offset: accountContext.accountState.data.accountsOffset,
        limit: accountContext.accountState.data.accountsLimit
      }
  })

  const { 
    loading: loadingAccountsTotal, 
    error: errorAccountsTotal, 
    data: dataAccountsTotal,
    refetch: refetchAccountsTotal
  } = useQuery(TOTAL_ACCOUNTS)

  const [
    updateAccount,
    { loading, error, data: updateAccountData }
  ] = useMutation(UPDATE_ACCOUNT);

  const setParentIDsHandler = (id) => {
    setParentAccountIDs(String(id))
  }

  const setOffset = (offset, limit) => {
    accountContext.accountDispatch({
      type: SET_ACCOUNTS_OFFSET, 
      payload: {
        offset: offset
      }
    })

    accountContext.accountDispatch({
      type: SET_ACCOUNTS_LIMIT,
      payload: {
        limit: limit
      }
    })
  }

  const deactivateUser = row => {
    updateAccount({
      variables: {
        account: {
          id: row.id,
          isActive: !row.isActive
        }
      }
      })
      accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_IS_ACTIVE, payload: row.id})
    }

  const handleRequestSort = (sortType, sortBy) => {
    sortRow(sortBy)
    setSortByType(sortType)
  }

  const sortRow = (sortBy) => {
    switch(sortBy) {
      case 'Contact':
        setSortByField('email')
        break
      case 'First Name':
        setSortByField('firstName')
        break
      case 'Last Name':
        setSortByField('lastName')
        break
      case 'Join Date':
        setSortByField('dateJoined')
        break
    }
  }

  const setDates = (dates) => {
    console.log("SETTING DATES", dates)
    if ("startDate" === Object.keys(dates)[0]) {
      setStartDate(dates.startDate)
    } else {
      setEndDate(dates.endDate)
    }
  }

  const checkDatesValid = () => {
    if (startDate && endDate) {
      if (startDate <= endDate) {
        return setDatesValid(true)
      }
    }
    return setDatesValid(false)
  }

  const clearDates = () => {
    console.log("CLEARING")
    setDatesValid(true)
    setStartDate(null)
    setEndDate(null)
    setSearchText(null)
    accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS_START_DATE, payload: {startDate: null}})
    accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS_END_DATE, payload: {endDate: null}})
    return setDatesValid(true)
  }

  const searchByChars = (text) => {
    console.log("SEARCH TEXT", text)
    setSearchText(text)
    resetAccounts()
  }

  const resetAccounts = () => {
    console.log("RESET ACCOUNTS TRIGGERED")
    refetchAccounts({
      variables: {
        parentIds: parentAccountIDs,
        offset: accountContext.accountState.data.accountsOffset,
        limit: accountContext.accountState.data.accountsLimit
      }
    })

    console.log("LOADING", loadingAccounts)
    console.log("ERROR", errorAccounts)
  }

  const filterText = (textRows) => {
    let newTextRows = []
    for (let row of textRows) {
        Object.entries(row['users'][0]).forEach(([key, val]) => {
          if (String(val).includes(String(searchText))) {
            if (!(newTextRows.includes(row))) {
              newTextRows.push(row)
            }
          }
        });
    }
    accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS, payload: {accounts: newTextRows}})
  }

  const filterDates = (dateRows) => {
    let newDateRows = []
    for (let row of dateRows) {
      if (datesValid) {
        const _date = moment(row.users[0]['dateJoined'])
        const sdate = moment(startDate)
        const edate = moment(endDate)
        if (_date.isBetween(sdate, edate, null, '[]')) {
          if (!(newDateRows.includes(row))) {
            newDateRows.push(row)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS, payload: {accounts: newDateRows}})
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sortByField && sortByType) {
      const newRows = accountContext.accountState.data.accounts.sort((a, b) => {
        const compareA = a.users[0][sortByField]
        const compareB = b.users[0][sortByField]
        if (compareA || compareB) {
          if ("DESC" === sortByType) {
            let comparison = 0;
            if (compareA > compareB) {
              comparison = 1;
            } else if (compareA < compareB) {
              comparison = -1;
            }
            return comparison;
          } else {
            let comparison = 0;
            if (compareA < compareB) {
              comparison = 1;
            } else if (compareA > compareB) {
              comparison = -1;
            }
            return comparison;
          }
        }
      })
      accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS, payload: newRows})
    }
    if (dataAccountsTotal) {
      accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS_TOTAL, payload: dataAccountsTotal})
    }
    if (dataAccountUsers) {
      setParentIDsHandler(dataAccountUsers.accountUsers[0].account.id)
      accountContext.accountDispatch({type: GET_PARENT_ACCOUNT, payload: dataAccountUsers})
    }
    if (dataAccounts) {
        console.log("NEW DATA", searchText, startDate, endDate, datesValid)
        console.log("SEARCH TEXT", searchText)
        console.log("START DATE", startDate)
        console.log("END DATE", endDate)
        accountContext.accountDispatch({type: SET_ACCOUNTS, payload: dataAccounts})
        console.log("DATES VALID", datesValid)
        if (startDate 
            && endDate && datesValid) {
          console.log("FILTER BY DATES")
          filterDates(accountContext.accountState.data.accounts)
        }
        if (searchText) {
          filterText(dataAccounts)
        }
      }
  }, [
    loadingAccounts,
    dataAccounts,
    dataAccountsTotal,
    dataAccountUsers,
    parentAccountIDs,
    updateAccountData,
    sortByField,
    sortByType,
    searchText
  ])

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {
        accountContext.accountState.data.accounts && 
        !loadingAccountUsers &&
        !errorAccountUsers &&
        !loadingAccounts &&
        !errorAccounts &&
        parentAccountIDs &&
        accountContext.accountState.data.accountUsers 
        ? <AccountsGrid 
          setOffset={setOffset}
          currentStartDate={startDate}
          currentEndDate={endDate}
          searchText={searchByChars}
          datesValid={datesValid}
          resetAccounts={resetAccounts}
          setDates={setDates}
          clearDates={clearDates}
          deactivateUser={deactivateUser}
          handleRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
          accountRows={accountContext.accountState.data.accounts}
        /> : <SpinnerLoader />}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
export default Accounts
```

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old question, but I had a similar issue and arrived here to an unanswered question.  I would like to share what I have learned about useEffect hook with Apollo Query or in any other use case, in the event it helps someone else.

useEffect hook does not actively "watch" and only triggers under select circumstances. Data loading from a graphql query is not one of the triggers.   useEffect will run :

- **After** re-rendering of the layout when the component **mounts**
- If the **state** changes of the component
- If the **props** of the component change
- When the component **unmounts**

Please check out this [amazing article](https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/) for more details.

Also if the variable is placed in the dependency array at the end of the useEffect hook, *by design*, it will NOT run if there are no changes to the variable.

So in order to trigger useEffect after data is loaded from an Apollo query you would have to make one of those conditions happen when the data loads.

It was much easier in my case to simply use the data after loading because trying to sync setState which is async with data loading which is async created some varied and unpredictable results.

It did help to use the parent class and pass in a variable as a prop which would trigger useEffect to setState when it changed.  The variable was used in the actual Apollo query so it made sense to the overall design.

Here is an example:

```js
    export const ResultsGrid = ( queryTerm ) => {
        const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
        const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_RESULTS_QUERY, {variables: { searchTerm }, }) 
        

        useEffect(() => {setSearchTerm(queryTerm)}
       ,[queryTerm]) //useEffect will run only when queryTerm changes 

        if (loading) return <p>Loading data from query...</p>
        if (error)         
          return (
              <React.Fragment>
              <p>Sorry, unable to fetch results. </p>
              <button onClick={() => refetch}>Please try again!</button>
              {console.log("error", error)}
              </React.Fragment>       
          )
       
        console.log('data:', data)
        console.log('loading:', loading)
       
        
          
        const { results } = data
        
       return (

         //display data results here

       )
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this is helpful and answers the question.